# Change default search URL slug in wordpress with Custop Post Type as Search target

Tags: search, slug

I want to change default search page URL **from**:
`http://example.com/?s=background&post_type=download`

**to:**
`http://example.com/photos/background/`

I tried to change the below function for the default search page:

```
function wp_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }  
 }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_change_search_url' );
```

The above function works ok but not working with custom post type searches.

In my theme I want to search only my custom post type named `download` and currently the function searches all posts & pages. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Vijay you can try to add post_type as query perameter in you redirect url check following changes in your code.

```
function wp_change_search_url() { 
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) { 
        get_query_var( 'post_type' );
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) . '?post_type=' . get_query_var( 'post_type' ) ); exit(); 
    }
} 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_change_search_url' );
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh,

Your suggested solution is working fine but I still have small edit if you can help me.

I want to include "photos" word in Search URL slug for example http://photoloch.com/photos/search/Beautiful+flower?post_type=download

Comment: I think you can do that using Add rewrite rules but it get little complex https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule